# TFS Create Branch from folder and rename it with one checkin

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, branch

I have a Folder "$/MyTeamProj/Sources" in TFS with some projects in it.
There is no branch in the team project.

Now I want to create a Branch of this folder with the name "Dev".
When I click on "convert to branch" I cannot change the Branchname.

I don't want to rename it and checkin and afterwards create the branch and checkin again.
I want only one checkin. The branch should keep history from the folder.

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Right click on the folder.
- Choose "Bracnhing and Merging".
- Don't click on "Convert to branch", click on "Branch...".
- In the "Target" type: "$/MyTeamProj/Sources/Dev".
- Click OK.

[image]